# div is moving very slowly

Tags: javascript

I am trying to move a div (avatar).

I get final position by clicking on page, so i run the move function,

```
var avi =  document.getElementById('avi_div');

move(start_left, start_top, end_left, end_top,avi)


function move(a,b,c,d,e) { 
    if ((a != c) || (b != d) ) {

        (c > a) ? a++ : a--;
        (d > b) ? b++ : b--;

        e.style.left = a  +'px';
        e.style.top = b  +'px';

        setTimeout(function(){ move(a,b,c,d,e)}, 1);
    }
}
```

well, it works, but although the timer is set to 1, it moves just good in Chrome, but very slowly in Firefox and extremely slow in IE

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it make sense to use jquery .animate().
Also be aware of... +"px" is not for each browsers. And try setInterval/clearInterval functions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i really want to find out why this function does not work well.
The movement is better than .animate() (it walks diagonal until top=end_top) and the 'px' also works fine.
I do not get an error, it just moves slowly.

Comment: ok. Look at delay value (in miliseconds as i know), it can be very small value for IE. Set 500ms and check, that the script is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference to the minimum delay used in different browsers.
see this post: http://ajaxian.com/archives/settimeout-delay  (it also suggests another method of timing events to 0 delays that you might try).

As xcompl suggests - it seems better to use `setInterval` here.

Also read http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/ to get some understanding of the behind the scenes of timers in Javascript.
Is there anything else going on the page to get in the way of your timer? some Javascript engines might handle it better than others...